# What is the mechanism of the reaction of ethyl prop-2-ynoate to ethyl (2Z)-2,3-dibromoprop-2-enoate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry, synthesis

[image]

It's really weird for the product is 99％ Z-comformation?
Please tell me why? 
This reaction can be found in scifinder.

Comment: Welcome to chem SE, try to add some attempt at the question and don't just ask for an answer. let us know your thoughts on the problem

Comment: In regards to the question, you are adding one molecules of $\ce{Br2}$ across the triple bond to leave a double bond. Hence it is an electrophilic addition reaction

Comment: But why the product is z-comformation is the problem as in usual the product is e-confirmation

Comment: I would assume steric hindrance will have a large factor to play in the reaction as the bromine is a large-ish thing to have on the side of the molecule when next to the carbonyl

Answer (score 3):

A search of SciFinder will also produce the formation of the (*E*)-dibromide **3**. The conditions described for the formation of the (*Z*)-dibromide **2** are taken from a paper by Myers<sup>1</sup> as reported earlier by Tippett.<sup>2</sup> Rossi<sup>3</sup> has reported the formation of the (*E*)-dibromide **3** using pyridinium hydrobromide perbromide. 
Given the more vigorous conditions for the formation of the (*Z*)-isomer **2** compared to the milder conditions for the formation of the (*E*)-isomer **3** suggests that the former reaction is under thermodynamic control while the latter is kinetically controlled.  There is the distinct possibility that bromine radicals may effect the isomerization via species **4** as may surreptitious acid.

[image]
1) A. G. Myers, M. M. Alauddin, M. A. M. Fuhry, P. S. Dragovich, N. S. Finney, and P. M. Harrington, *Tetrahedron Letters*, **1989**, *30*, 6997.
2) R. G. Hall and S. Trippett, *Tetrahedron Letters*, **1982**, *23*, 2603.
3) F. Bellina, A. Carpita, M. De Santis and R. Rossi, *Tetrahedron Letters*, **1994**, *35*, 6913.

Answer (score 2):

Although the following reaction is not syn dibromination, the following reaction sequence is a example of syn dichlorination from https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Catalytic%2C-stereospecific-syn-dichlorination-of-Cresswell-Eey/a53c83d35d5acf0a7ac1311bd9462dedd2dc666f .

The possible mechanism is follows.[image]